# Install 4.0 Linux Kernel od Ubuntu 14.04 i686

Tags: kernel

I like to install linux 4.0 kernel on ubuntu 14.04 but i don't find any file for i686.

Answer (score 0):

You can find 4.0 kernel image and headers in [Ubuntu Kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/)

For 32-bit systems you will need `i386` packages.

But it is not recommended to install unsupported kernels, if you do not have a really good reason to do it. You can get all kinds of troubles. Some drivers may not build, etc.